# How to remove one particular edge in a graph macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I currently have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[nodes={circle, draw}] { subgraph K_n [n=4,clockwise, radius=1.5cm]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{Not} a planar map}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces this graph:

[image]

I now want to remove the edge connecting the vertices (1) and (3), and replace it with something that bends out the graph. Here is, my attempt:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[nodes={circle, draw}] { subgraph K_n [n=4,clockwise, radius=1.5cm], 1 -- [bend left] 3 };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Planar representation of above graph}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Now, of-course, this doesn't remove the previous edge, so I have an extra edge. In addition, I am unsure how to change the amount the edge bends so that it no longer intersects any other edge. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying that the graph is *simple*, one can modify the edges of a graph macro:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={circle,draw},simple] {
    subgraph K_n [n=4,clockwise,radius=1.5cm];
    1 --[bend left] 3;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: desired output]

And even remove them (as asked in the title of the question), with the special `-!-` edge specification:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={circle,draw},simple] {
    subgraph K_n [n=4,clockwise,radius=1.5cm];
    1 -!- 3;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[Link to the explanation in the docs](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/simple)

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle, draw] (a) at   (0:1) {$2$};
  \node[circle, draw] (b) at  (90:1) {$1$} edge (a);
  \node[circle, draw] (c) at (180:1) {$4$} edge (a) edge (b);
  \node[circle, draw] (d) at (270:1) {$3$} edge (a) edge (b) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle, draw] (a) at   (0:1) {$2$};
  \node[circle, draw] (b) at  (90:1) {$1$} edge (a);
  \node[circle, draw] (c) at (180:1) {$4$} edge (a) edge (b);
  \node[circle, draw] (d) at (270:1) {$3$} edge (a) edge (c);
  \node[radius=0pt, outer sep=-0.5pt, inner sep=0pt] (e) at (0:1.9) {}
  edge [bend right=55] (b) edge [bend left=55] (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]